# Поиск динамично изменяющегося значения в многомерном ассоциативном массиве

Tags: php, mysql

Уважаемые посетители. Есть вопрос. Суть ситуации - необходимо осуществить поиск динамично изменяющегося id в многомерном ассоциативном массиве. 
$id может соответствовать одной из записей, которую возвращает запрос mysql.

Пробовал делать перебор функцией in_array, также смотрел примеры, нашел несколько статей на подобную тему, но увы...

П.С. $id - это табельный номер сотрудника + текущая дата, если в месяце 30 дней, то соответственно на 1 сотрудника 30 уникальных ид.

```
$id = strtoupper($info[$i]['tabno'])."-".$gluing_date; // делаю уникальный id для каждого элемента <td>, чтобы записывать данные, возвращаемые запросом в нужную ячейку

$sql = "SELECT tabno, work_date, cause 
          FROM month_detail
         WHERE tabno = '".strtoupper($info[$i]['tabno'])."'
           AND work_date = '".$gluing_date."'
        ";  

$query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql); //Выполнение запроса в БД;

// цикл отрисовки ячеек таблицы         
$t=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $arr[$t]['cause'] = $row['cause'];
    $arr[$t]['concat'] = $row['tabno']."-".$row['work_date'];

    if (in_array($id,$arr)){ //проверка $id клетки <td> в получаемом массиве, чтобы записать конкретную запись именно в этот id
        echo "<td class='day'; id='".$id."'> ".$arr[$t]['cause']." </td>";  // если $id есть в массиве $arr, то отрисовать <td> с содержимым из БД
    } else {
        echo "<td class='day'; id='".$id."'> &nbsp; </td>"; // если нет - рисовать пустую клетку
    }
    $t++;
}
```

Comment: вы вообще понимаете что у вас в коде этом происходит? Тут начиная с `while` к каждой строке кода можно вопросы задавать. Возможно, вам будет достаточно проверить `$id == $row['tabno'].'-'.$row['work_date']` если форматы даты совпадают.

Comment: зы: по сабжу, вам не надо мульти-массив просматривать. вы работаете только с текущей строкой, то есть вам нужен только `$arr[$t]` или проще `$row`. зы2: `$row['id']` всегда нулл, его нет в запросе.

Comment: По второму комментарию: по невнимательности не поправил данные.

Comment: По первому, сделал сравнение:

if ($id == $arrDay[$t]['concat'])

Но выводит только то, что возвращается запросом, пусты клетки не отрисовывает.

Comment: дак вы и в самом запросе выбираете только такие данные, или нет? не ясно вообще, что у вас хранится в `work_date`, вряд ли это конкретная дата ведь, месяц что ли?

Comment: при внесении информации о графике, генерится и записывается в базу каждый день в формате гггг-мм-дд, именно он и выводится в переменной work_date

Comment: Что у вас в $gluing_date дата или номер месяца? И какое отношение имеет "поиск в многомерном массиве" к том что вы в where в sql делаете, вы хотите искать на php или в MySQL?

Comment: $gluing_date - дата в формате гггг-мм-дд, она нужна для того, чтобы каждой клетке таблицы присвоить свой ид. Т.е. для конкретного сотрудника на конкретную дату будет свой ид. Например, на 08.03.2017 у сотрудника с табельным номером 1111 будет элемент td с ид 1111-2017-03-08. Поиск хочу делать на пхп, логика такая:
- мне ajax'ом приходят данные;
- анализируются и записываются в базу;
- потом я проверяю, если в базе запись есть по этому сотруднику, то хочу вывести ее в таблицу, если нет, то оставить клетки таблицы пустыми.

Comment: сейчас получается так, что я выбрал значения по таблице month_detail, а дальше в ифе, выполняется условие и возвращается только та информация, запись по которой нашлась, а элсе не выполнилось, т.е. пустые клетки не отрисовались. Я понимаю, что проблема из-за сравнения и логики отрисовки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо создать доп. переменную, если условие true - выполнять действие (моё случай - отрисовка  и изменять значение доп. переменной. Рабочий пример:

```
$flag = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$s++)
{
   if ($people[$j]['tabno'] == $array[$i]['tabno'] && $gluing_date == $array[$i]['work_date'])
   {
      echo "<td id='".$id."'; class='day'> ".$array[$i]['tabno']." </td>";
      $flag_cell=1;
   }
}
if ($flag == 0) 
{
   echo "<td id='".$id."'; class='day'></td>";
}
```